# How can I make this adventure more exciting?

Tags: adventure-writing, dungeon-design

I'm trying to make an adventure to advance a central plot and relate to a pc's history. It's set in a settlement with a civil werewolf population. Every full moon, they seclude themselves to protect the townsfolk. One night they are let loose. I'm trying to present a mystery of who did it and why people disappeared during that event. The culprit is found to be experimenting on victims freshly cursed with lycanthropy. I don't feel very satisfied or engaged while working on this, even though I think it's a good idea. How can I make it more exciting/engaging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a decent idea to me, OP. I think you just need to add more details and things that happen along the way, but you have the driving cause for an adventure in place. It sounds to me like you're making a more intrigue/mystery themed adventure rather than a straight-up hack-and-slash, so I'm going to write some suggestions with that in mind.

**Have a Trail of Clues That Leads to the Culprit**

Seems obvious, I know, but once you really set your mind to thinking on it you'll end up fleshing out your adventure a lot more than you thought you would. Leads can come from objects and NPCs; those objects can be in interesting places, and the NPCs can be interesting as well, maybe even have a small side-plot.

**Have a Cast of Interesting NPCs to Talk To**

This is kind of similar to the first one, but since your adventure takes place in a village and is a mystery, your players are going to have to do some inquiry. You should make an effort to have several NPCs that have a name, motivation, and maybe something significant that happened in their past; these three things are the beginning of making an engaging character from which new traits can emerge based on gameplay experiences. In one D&D game I played, there was an NPC bard that ended up following us around. He had an uncanny ability to roll critical hits and steal the credit for killing the most powerful enemy in a given encounter. An in-character rivalry emerged between the PCs and this damn bard, and we had good laughs about it. That's just one trait for one character.

**Roll for Random Encounters**

If your players are travelling or resting somewhere and they are itching for some XP progression or combat, you can throw in a random encounter roll while they're travelling or sleeping. I don't like having a lot of random encounters, but I do think that having an unexpected fight can make a game substantially more exciting depending on the circumstances. Plus, you've once again added a new element -- the encounter itself -- and you can find inspiration in building that encounter. Always build your random encounters ahead of time, though.

The most important thing is that any time you have another activity for the PCs to do -- fight in an encounter, find a clue, talk to someone -- you should consider expanding upon it, if possible. I'm not saying that every random encounter should actually have a campaign hidden in it; indeed, I don't end up fleshing out the majority of things that happen to my players, but you should consider it anyway.

Comment: It sounds like the poster is asking about how he or she might become more excited and engaged with his or her ideas/campaign, not how to get the PCs engaged.

Comment: On the topic of this answer though, taking the time to deliver really evocative descriptions (whether of characters, items, places, or actions) is also really helpful in engaging people.  Just make sure not to only do it when it's plot important.

Answer (score 5):

Your idea doesn't sound intrinsically uninteresting so that's not the problem.  Also, as you haven't actually run the game yet, it's not your players you need to make the game more 'exciting/engaging' for it's you.  You probably know best what motivates you to GM, but there are a number of common things that cause GM's to *lose* interest in their games.  I can't advise you much about what to do to *gain* interest, as that, as far as I can tell, varies widely between people.  But I might be able to help you realize causes of disinterest in the game.

### GM Burnout

If you only GM and haven't played in a long time, considering have one of your players or someone else run a game for you.  GMing is super awesome, but if you never RPG as a player you can start to forget what it's like, which detracts from the fun you can have GMing as well.  GMing is also hard, and if you are doing it too often, or prepping too much, or in general putting too much effort into it without enough perceived reward and/or enough rest time, you might just need to stop and take a breather.  Once you're well rested, things may seem exciting and new again since you have the emotional energy to really deal with them.

Really emotionally traumatic campaigns can also cause burnout, but that, I think, is less common.

### Problem Players

Sometimes (almost always in my experience) one of your players is a jerk or min-maxing in a way that bothers you or holds differing political views than you or makes jokes in bad taste or texts while gaming or any number of other things, and it's annoying to GM for.  That's not what I'm talking about here.  Much more rarely, the entire party, or at least a dominant majority of the players, put almost no effort into the game.  They may not pay attention to your descriptions, may repeatedly ask about things you just told them, may play side games at the table, etc.   Frequently this is a sign that they are not enjoying the game, but not always (and they may not be enjoying it just because they aren't engaged and not the other way around).  Regardless, putting a ton of effort into prepping scenarios for a group that doesn't care (or at least seems not to care) is very draining.  It's hard to gauge the quality of your scenarios because regardless of how much effort you put in or how on or off the ball you are on a given night you get the same amount out: nothing.  If your players aren't reacting to your game's ups and downs something is wrong and if you don't fix it it won't just kill your game, it'll make you not want to GM anymore.  Hopefully this isn't your problem, but if it is you need to call a quorum with your gaming group at the very least, and probably end the campaign.

### Bad System

Sometimes people use an RPG system because it's the only one they've been exposed to rather than because it's the one that really best fits their GMing style.  The doesn't mean the system is bad in general but it **does** mean it's bad for you.  Do you use D&D 3.5, D&D 4.0, or Pathfinder?  Have you ever GMed a game in a system other than these?  If your answer to the first question is yes and your answer to the second question is no, you really should try something else.  I mention those systems specifically because D&D is-- by far-- the most popular RPG system and I've run into many people who didn't even know there were others (Pathfinder is a different D&D 3.5.  It is not significantly different in any way.  It may be better or worse but it isn't different in the way Shadowrun, FATE, World of Darkness, or even D&D 2.0 is), not because these systems are necessarily worse for everyone, and maybe they are the best for you, but if you don't look around you'll never find out.  Personally, if this is your problem, I'd recommend looking into the World of Darkness stuff for your werewolf game.  It's a politically focused medium-rules system with a major focus on things like werewolves, vampires, and other humanoid 'dark' monsters.  Then, once this campaign is over, run FATE 2.0 (3.0 is good too but less different), Shadowrun 4th edition (I REALLY don't like 5th ed.  probably someone does though), and Amber Diceless to experience ultra-rules-light, ultra-rules-heavy (but not d&d), and ultra-political.  You could substitute Anima: Beyond Fantasy for Amber if that game seems a little too out in left field.

### GM Dread

Every good GM secretly thinks the thing they just made isn't any good, at least right before they run it.  It's different then actually thinking what you've made isn't good for actual, rational, reasons, and mostly comes from our innate human fear of rejection/failure.  With experience you can tell the difference, but if you're new to GMing it might just be that.  In that case, go ahead, your idea's fine and, unless there are player-specific issues, it sounds like it'll go great.